# Loop through checkboxes on a sheet

Tags: excel, vba

How would I create the following as a Loop.

Basically the first list to loop would be selectStatus, selectSite, These are check boxes on a sheet. (The below code only includes two but the full macro has about 60 to loop)

The second loop would be the values "Header 1", "Header 2", etc. so they would both loop and change together. The first one being the checkbox name and the second being a corresponding SQL header which I want at the end to create a string.

```
    Sub TEST2()

    If Sheets("controlSheet").selectStatus.Value = True Then
    a = "Header 1, "
    Else
    a = ""
    End If

    If Sheets("controlSheet").selectSite.Value = True Then
    a = a + "Header 2, "
    Else
    a = a + ""
    End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, but I think you have to elaborate this, especially your code, a bit further. It's pretty unclear (to me at least).

Comment: I agree with Tom. I can't understand what you are after. What do you have 60 of to loop?

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now. There are 60 checkboxes with different names and depending which of these are checked, you want to append `a` with `"Header X, "`. And now you need a loop, to loop through all checkboxes, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one header where you can create an object to hold a list of the mapping between control name and header name. Let me know of any questions.

Dim oDictHeaders As Object

```
Function GetHeaders() As Object
    If oDictHeaders Is Nothing Then
        Set oDictHeaders = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        oDictHeaders("SelectSite") = "Header 1"
        oDictHeaders("SelectStatus") = "Header 2"
        oDictHeaders("SelectOther") = "Header 3"
    End If

    Set GetHeaders = oDictHeaders
End Function


Function GetListOfHeaders() As String
    Dim sOutput As String
    Dim oDict As Object
    Dim ctl As Object

    sOutput = ""

    Set oDict = GetHeaders()

    For Each ctl In Sheet1.OLEObjects
    Debug.Print TypeName(ctl.Object)
        If TypeName(ctl.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
            If ctl.Object.Value = True Then
                sOutput = sOutput & ", " & oDict(ctl.Name)
            End If
        End If
    Next ctl

    GetListOfHeaders = Mid(sOutput, 2)
End Function

Sub Test()
    MsgBox (GetListOfHeaders())
End Sub
```

Comment: this works perfect! thank you. in the future, Ill look to pulling them straight from SQL table, but i'm new to it so one step at a time!

thanks again!

Comment: @LawrenceFerguson Glad I could help. Please mark the question as answered so other users know that it is closed.     You can chain solutions together. You can populate the dictionary object with key/value pairs that are pulled from a SQL table. This allows for a more dynamic solution where adding a new checkbox/filter doesn't require you to go into VBA to modify the code. You can just add a new checkbox in the Workbook with a corresponding row in the SQL table storing mappings.

Answer (score 2):

This should handle ActiveX checkboxes.

**NOTE:** This requires your checkboxes are indexed correctly (i.e., the *first* one by index will correspond to "Header 1", the second with "Header 2", the *n*th with "Header *n*", etc...). If they are out of order, you'd need additional logic to control for that (see [the other answer for a good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38617888/1467082) if that is the case).

```
Option Explicit
Sub LoopActiveXCheckBoxes()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim obj As OLEObject
Dim cb As CheckBox
Dim i As Long
Dim a As String

Set ws = Sheets("controlSheet")
For Each obj In ws.OLEObjects
    If TypeName(obj.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
        i = i + 1
        If obj.Object.Value = True Then
            a = a & "Header " & CStr(i) & ","
        End If
    End If
Next
If Len(a) > 0 Then a = Left(a, Len(a) - 1)

End Sub
```

For Form Control checkboxes, this would work but I'm pretty sure you're using ActiveX.

```
Sub LoopCheckBoxes()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cb As CheckBox
Dim i As Long
Dim a As String

Set ws = Sheets("controlSheet")
For Each cb In ws.CheckBoxes
    i = i + 1
    If cb.Value = 1 Then
        a = a & "Header " & CStr(i) & ","
    End If
Next
If Len(a) > 0 Then a = Left(a, Len(a) - 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi yes I think your onto what I'm trying to do however, I wasn't super clear about it! Instead of header 1,2,3,n etc that was just an example. Each header is more like: BLBINL,BLBCOD,BLWARC...basically headers from an SQL table.

But yes I did plan to have them in logical order so selectSite would be first on list and the corressponding header "BLBCOD" would be first in 2nd list.

Comment: If you don't provide an example that is representative ofyour actual problem, then you're going to get answers like this one, which perfectly solve the problem as-stated, but do not solve your actual problem. IF you need to implement mapping, then use [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38617888/1467082).

Comment: Alternatively you can read the headers from SQL in to an array, and index that instead of hard-coding the `"Header " & ...` string.